# Snubber design for switching an inductive mains load with a relay

Tags: relay, inductive, snubber

I am envisaging a relay which switches an inductive load consisting of a couple of switched-mode power supplies (standard ATX computer power supplies) in addition to several wall-wart style power supplies powering other equipment.  The total power consumption is about 600 W at 220 VAC. The exact nature of the load may vary over time as different equipment is substituted, but what I have described is the typical size and character of the load.

I've been reading about snubber designs and it seems that some combination of a RC snubber and/or a bidirectional TVS (Transorb/Tranzorb) diode in parallel with the load would be required.  I'm not comfortable with the alternative design of snubbing in parallel with the *contacts* because I want zero current flow when the relay contacts are open.  Something like the diagram in this 
application note for [Driving and Relay and Contact Snubbing](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/Resources/pdf/mi-an-040drive&snubarelay.pdf) [PDF] is what I imagine.

First of all, what combination of snubber components is appropriate for my situation - RC network, TVS diode or maybe a MOV?  Secondly how can I conservatively estimate the values and ratings of the required components to ensure that my relay contacts don't erode or weld?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RC network's purpose is to provide a dampened path for the charge stored in the inductor. The MOV and TVS diode purposes' is to limit the high voltage that may appear. So they're complementary. Use both a RC network plus either the MOV or TVS.

I used 100 nF + 100 ohm for my loads for years and never had any problems so that's a couple of starting values.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd noticed that 100 nF + 100 ohm appeared to be very common and a sort of default value for such RC networks, but I didn't want to jump the gun without being better informed.

Comment: Can you provide any guidance on TVS selection? The [1.5KE](http://www.littelfuse.com/products/TVS+Diodes/Axial+Lead/1.5KE.html) series seems widely used.  Given my 220 V RMS potential (which is 311 V peak) it looks like the 1.5KE400CA bidirectional TVS might work.  It has a 342 V reverse stand-off voltage a ~400 V breakdown voltage, but its maximum peak pulse current is (only?) 2.8 A. Is that likely to be enough?  Is there a simple way to determine this?

Comment: @RobSmallshire Just to answer your question (for anyone else who may have it), you want to pay attention to three characteristics. 

A) TVS Peak pulse power rating > Max power of the relay's load
B) TVS Max reverse standoff voltage > Relay's switching voltage  (not Vrms, make sure to use PEAK voltage, ie (240Vrms = 340Vp)
C) TVS Max clamping voltage < relay contact breakdown voltage

Comment: A TVS diode works to dampen the inductive energy with or without a RC snubber. The only difference is that the snubber is active when ANY AC voltage is across it, whereas a properly spec'd TVS only activates during an inductive spike event. Bottom line: The TVS by itself is OK for protecting the relay contacts. In fact, your solid state relays often have a sole TVS built-in. Just make sure it's sized properly.